# Snake Keeps Spawning Outside of Walls in Snake Game(C++)

Tags: c++

I am coding a basic snake game in C++ for a class, but it sometimes spawns outside of the designated walls I created. Is there a simple fix to have the snake spawn within the walls? Thank you for any and all help!

Below is what I have coded to make the snake appear, my professor has done most of the work in other files, I just need to implement functions to make the snake visible.

```
//integers
int x = WIDTH / 2;
int y = HEIGHT / 2;

//code for making walls
void draw_walls(char board[HEIGHT + 2][WIDTH + 2]) {
  for (int j = 0; j < (WIDTH + 2); j++) {
    board[0][j] = '#';
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < (HEIGHT + 1); i++) {
    board[i][0] = '#';
    for (int j = 1; j <= (WIDTH + 2); j++) {
      board[i][j] = ' ';
    }
    board[i][(WIDTH + 1)] = '#';
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < (WIDTH + 2); j++) {
    board[HEIGHT + 1][j] = '#';
  }
  return;
}

//code for drawing snake
void draw_snake(char board[HEIGHT + 2][WIDTH + 2], const std::vector<Pos> snake) {
  board[snake.front().x][snake.front().y] = '@';
  for (size_t i = 1; i < snake.size(); i++) {
    board[snake[i].x][snake[i].y] = 'O';
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at our [intro section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), with special attention to the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You have not shown us the code that spawns the snake, so there's really no way we can help you. If your professor wrote that code, then you should talk to your professor about the bug.

Comment: The relevant part is most likely the snake vector, as it describes the position of the snake parts. Could you show us the code that populates this snake vector?